# Solution for adapter when data wait to load

Tags: android, listview, exception, asynchronous

Items in my **`ListView`** needs time to load, so I create threads to load them, thus making load operation **asynchronous**. I have 10 items in the list. Item 10 can be loaded, but item 9 is loading.

I made a custom **Adapter** with **ArrayList**, initialized with 10 elements (data empty).

In **getView()** function, I check if it is loading (`data empty`) I return null, and notify when have an item loaded.

But it reports **exception** in **onLayout** function of `ListView`.

Please help me a solution for this case.

---

UPDATED:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Item model = arrayList.get(position / 3);
        if(model.getId()==null) return null;
        if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null || !                (convertView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolderHeader)) {
        .......
        }
        ......
     }
```

---

UPDATE LOG FILE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
                                                            at com.packed.customviews.LoadMoreListView.createPinnedShadow(LoadMoreListView.java:269)
                                                            at com.packed.customviews.LoadMoreListView.ensureShadowForPosition(LoadMoreListView.java:325)
                                                            at com.packed.customviews.LoadMoreListView$2.onScroll(LoadMoreListView.java:160)
                                                            at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1938)
                                                            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:7065)
                                                            at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:6484)
                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: please show the full stack trace and also some codes

Comment: Hi, my code very simple. In getView() the first I check getItem(position) if it empty getView will return null (not layout).

Comment: show your simple code

Comment: You can't just return null in `getView()`.  That is what is causing the exception. You have to either display a placeholder `View` for items which are not yet loaded or not handle them at all in your `Adapter` until they have been loaded.  So short answer: Never return null in `getView() `

Comment: show your stack trce..

Comment: But my data on that position not loaded, I can't fill data to it. What is solution ?

Comment: Yes, I have update log file. I think becase getView return null, some function return NullPointerException. I need a solution for my case. I need keep order of item and speed of view (Item loaded need show && not load need hidden)

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to display 10 loading items in your list view, and when each item is loaded, its cell in the list is updated. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another view that will contain a text (loading... ) or use existing convertView (with little bit change like set text loading... or something that user can understand that this item is under loading )

```
    if(model.getId()==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    loadingView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_branch_location,parent,false);

    return loadingView;        
    }
```

and set this logic when finish your backgroud process for loading original item then loadingView will be replaced... and notified

Comment: Hi, I use VISIBLE and GONE for it. If data empty view is GONE. but bottom listview is very long and gray.

Comment: Use Visible and gone may be not suitable for this scenario

Comment: Sory, I think your solution is good. But in my case ListView is pinned header.